# Want to save every page I browse to

Tags: browser, offline-files

I'm looking for the ability to save every web page I look at within the browser, then check for updates to the page on a customizable schedule.

The offline browsers I've seen appear to just download a website to a certain number of links down, then enable you to look at what has been downloaded.

The browser extensions that do this that I have seen require each page to be saved individually, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do the offline browsing in a different way... instead of a offline browser, use a offline proxy.

you browser the web with the offline proxy and they save the pages. when you disconnect, you can still see all the pages you had visit. You use a normal browser and just have to configure the browser proxy to start browsing with offline capability

you have several options, check examples:

http://www.proxy-offline-browser.com/ for windows

http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/ for linux and other unix (can also run in windows via cygwin)